# I uploaded customer's server one single js function doesnt work

Tags: javascript

I finished customers site and uploaded it on their server they use hostinger as well as me.
in localhost and my hosting everything works perfect but in their hosting just one function refuses working. Its pure javascript no library used.The duty of the function is to change a flag when it is clicked.

```
function lang() {
  var a = document.getElementById("flag").firstChild;
  a = (a.nodeType == 1) ? a : a.nextSibling;
  var active = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  var actid = (a.src.indexOf("uk.png") == -1) ? active[0].id.replace("fr", "en") : active[0].id.replace("en", "fr");
  active[0].className = active[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  document.getElementById(actid).className += " active";
  return a.id;
}
document.getElementById("flag").addEventListener("click", lang);
```

Comment: "function refuses working" - is too an anthropomorphic description. It refuses? Make it!

Comment: no console errors it just says a photo corrupted what works well but about this function no error

Comment: "it just says a photo corrupted what works well but about this function no error" - what does that mean? What is "it"? What photo is being corrupted? Is it that there's no error message in the console, but something is still very obviously going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem It was in another script.
I was using `indexOf()` to check whether the flag source has "fr"
if it doesn't i was changing into french.
Domain was .fr and because of this it returned bigger than -1 and function didnt work it was such simple problem.